# How to fill a string with random (hex) characters?

Tags: c, linux

I have a string (unsigned char) and i want to fill it with only hex characters.

my code is

```
unsigned char str[STR_LEN] = {0};
for(i = 0;i<STR_LEN;i++) {
    sprintf(str[i],"%x",rand()%16);
}
```

Of course, when running this I get segfaulted

Answer (score 8):

1. string is an array of `char`-s not `unsigned char`-s
2. you are using `str[i]` (which is of type `unsigned char`) as a 1st argument to `sprintf`, but it requires type `char *` (pointer).

This should be a little better:

```
char str[STR_LEN + 1];
for(i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i++) {
    sprintf(str + i, "%x", rand() % 16);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to [`sprintf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be a `char*`, but `str[i]` is a `char`: **this is the cause of the segmentation fault**. The compiler should have emitted a warning about this. `gcc main.c`, without specifying a high warning level, emitted the following:

> warning: passing argument 1 of sprintf makes pointer from integer without a cast

A hex representation of a character can be 1 or 2 characters (`9` or `AB` for example). For formatting, set the precision to `2` and the fill character to `0`. Also need to add one character for the terminating null to `str` and set the step of the `for` loop to `2` instead of `1` (to prevent overwriting previous value):

```
unsigned char str[STR_LEN + 1] = {0};
int i;

for (i = 0; i < STR_LEN; i += 2)
{
    sprintf(&str[i], "%02X", rand() % 16);
}
```

Comment: Although you're mostly correct, `rand()%16` will allways result in only one character ('0' - 'F'), also no need for null termination, because `sprintf` will take care of that.

Comment: @JanSpurny, I know `sprintf()` inserts the null terminator, but it needs somewhere to put it. However, I had not realised the range of results from `rand() % 16`.

Comment: It will overrun the buffer, sure, but the zero character will be written there. Of course it can be overwritten at any moment after that, but it's the problem with unsifficient allocated memory, not with `sprintf` not writing final `\0`. As you've added +1 there's enough room for it. As for the referenced example - can't see your point - it compiles (with warnings) and it works. But it prints unneccessary zeroes betfore every hex number.

Comment: @JanSpurny, what warnings (I get no warnings with VC8,9 or 10 apart from security) or with gcc. The leading zero is a fill character, useful if the range was not restricted where the hex value could be a single character or two characters.

Comment: gcc warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of ‘sprintf’ differ in signedness
/usr/include/stdio.h:341: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char *’

Comment: Also, as I've already said, `rand % 16` can ONLY produce one hexadecimal digit. So making space for another one is utterly pointless.

Comment: @JanSpurny, I know what you said regarding the single digit. I had coded to handle the case where that was not the case (superfluous in this case, I agree) and, personally, I prefer the double character representation for hex.

Comment: But that's not what he wanted, he just wanted some random hex-digits. If you like to do anything else, it's fine, but it has no place in answering this specific question. I might as well say I like "dinosaur" printed before any hex-digit and you'd agree that wouldn't be very helpful :)

Comment: @JanSpurny, the phrase _hex character_ I find ambiguous and I took it to mean _the hex value of a character_. It might be obvious to you, but it was not to me. This answer is relevant as it a) provides the reason for segmentation fault and b) provides a solution which the OP may or not like the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define STR_LEN 20

int main(void)
{
   unsigned char str[STR_LEN + 1] = {0};
   const char *hex_digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
   int i;

   for( i = 0 ; i < STR_LEN; i++ ) {
      str[i] = hex_digits[ ( rand() % 16 ) ];
   }

   printf( "%s\n", str );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to use `srand()` because your function generates the same hex every time

Answer (score 0):

There are several unclarities and problems in your code. I interpret "hex character" to mean "hex digit", i.e. a symbol from {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,e,f}, not "the hexadecimal value of an ascii character's code point". This might or might not be what you meant.

This should do it:

```
void hex_fill(char *buf, size_t max)
{
  static const char hexdigit[16] = "0123456789abcdef";
  if(max < 1)
    return;
  --max;
  for(i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    buf[i] = hexdigit[rand() % sizeof hexdigit];
  buf[max] = '\0';
}
```

The above will always 0-terminate the string, so there's no requirement that you do so in advance. It will properly handle all buffer sizes.

Answer (score 0):

My variation on some of answers below; note the time seeded rand function and instead of a char using a const size, I use a vector that is then converted to a string array.

[Boost variate generator docs](https://valelab4.ucsf.edu/svn/3rdpartypublic/boost/doc/html/boost/variate_generator.html)

```
std::string GetRandomHexString(unsigned int count)
{
    std::vector<char> charVect = std::vector<char>(count);
    //Rand generator
    typedef boost::random::mt19937 RNGType;
    RNGType rng(std::time(nullptr) + (unsigned int)clock()); 
    //seeding rng
    uniform_int<> range(0, 15); //Setting min max
    boost::variate_generator<RNGType, boost::uniform_int<> >generate(rng, range); //Creating our generator
    //Explicit chars to sample from
    const char hexChars[16] = { '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F' };
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        charVect[i] = hexChars[generate()];
    }
    //
    return std::string(charVect.begin(), charVect.end());;
}
```

Examples (count = 32):

- 1B62C49C416A623398B89A55EBD3E9AC
- 26CFD2D1C14B9F475BF99E4D537E2283
- B8709C1E87F673957927A7F752D0B82A
- DFED20E9C957C4EEBF4661E7F7A58460
- 4F86A631AE5A05467BA416C4854609F8